# Problem with SD card and new Zoom H5

Tags: zoom

In my testing of my new Zoom H5, I foolishly did not test the standalone recording capabilities, which require a working SD card.

I tried using the included SD card. When I tried to format it, I got an error. When I tried the quick performance test, it alternately gave me NG, and just froze part of the way through.

I have like one day left to return this to Amazon India. Should I do so or not? I just checked my account and it says returnable till July 7th. It's now the morning of the 6th (local time is IST = UTC+5.30). So I don't have a lot of time to think about it.

Even assuming it is a corrupt SD card, should the Zoom freeze like that? And if it is not corrupt, something is clearly wrong. I don't have any other way to test the SD card. Should I buy another SD card and try it with that. As you can see, I don't have much time.

BTW, could someone create a Zoom H5 tag?

Comment: July 7 is not one day from today :)

Comment: Did you make sure that the lock slide on the SD card is in the unlocked position?

Comment: @Timinycricket Yes, that's not the issue. If it's locked, then it says that the card is protected.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because support issue for zoom and/or amazon

Answer (score 0):

Your distributor will not be interested in the hassle of a full return if it is likely that just the card is broken.  So how about asking him for further guidance?  If he tells you that you can still return the H5 in the next two weeks in case that a replacement card does not do the trick, you know what to do.  If he doesn't reply in time to make a decision, you can send back the package, no question asked.

Sometimes it is sufficient to announce your intent of sending it back in order to meet the return deadlines.  You can make that announcement conditional on getting guarantees that you are not disadvantaged when figuring out that it's indeed the H5 is broken.

Comment: I tried a different card. I got the same error. Unless the H5 is very sensitive to the type of SD card (I hope it isn't) this shouldn't happen. I suppose there is a remote chance that the card is defective. But regardless, even if the card is defective, the unit shouldn't hang. That certainly seems like a red flag.

Comment: I don't think trying to make arrangements with distributors in India (read random strangers who might be a bit crooked or crazy) is calculated to improve my mental health. I'm just returning it to Amazon India.